# violation of primary key constraint 'pk_'. cannot insert duplicate key in object wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, code-first

I used **entity framework code first**.I have 3 tables . my tables are :

```
-Product :{name id ...}

-property :{name id }

-productProperty:{productId propertyId value}
```

know when I editing my product I want to add new property to this product.
So my code is :

```
  listProducts.Remove(curentProduct);
                curentProduct.productName = txtname.Text;
                curentProduct.ProductImage = BitmapSourceToByteArray((BitmapSource)imgPhoto.Source);
                curentProduct.Cat = findCategory(cbCatnewpro.SelectedItem.ToString());
                curentProduct.productCode = txtProductCode.Text;
                curentProduct.productInfo = txtInfo.Text;
                curentProduct.productPrice = txtPrice.Text;
                curentProduct.productTEdada = Convert.ToInt32(txtTedad.Text);
                List<dginfocomper> list = new List<dginfocomper>();
                for (int i = 0; i < dgPro.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    dginfocomper d = dgPro.Items[i] as dginfocomper;
                    list.Add(d);
                }
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    if (item == null)
                        break;
                    foreach (var item1 in curentProduct.ProductsProperties.ToList())
                    {

                        int id = findpropertyId(item.m0);
                        if (id == item1.propertyID)
                        {
                            item1.value = item.m1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
                int y = list.Count - curentProduct.ProductsProperties.ToList().Count;
                int x = curentProduct.ProductsProperties.ToList().Count - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < y-1; i++)
                {
                    ProductProperty pp = new ProductProperty();
                    pp.propertyID = findpropertyId(list[x].m0);
                    pp.value = list[x].m1;
                   curentProduct.ProductsProperties.Add(pp);
                    x--;
                }
                listProducts.Add(curentProduct);
                entity.SaveChanges();
                dgRowProFill(curentProduct);
                MessageBox.Show("با موفقیت ثبت شد");
```

But I get below error :

> {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.ProductProperties'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ProductProperties'. The duplicate key value is (1, 7).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

I googling But I cant find my probleam .So How Can I fix it?

Comment: have you tried removing the curentProduct from the database (and saving your changes) before re-adding it?

Comment: The database is telling you that you are inserting a ProductProperty that has the same primary key as an existing ProductProperty.  Not sure what is wrong with your code that it is causing that though, if anything.

Answer (score 0):

As @sous2817 [mentioned in a comment:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41834107/violation-of-primary-key-constraint-pk-cannot-insert-duplicate-key-in-object/41834602#comment70854925_41834107)

> have you tried removing the curentProduct from the database (and saving your changes) before re-adding it?

I deleted `productPropertys` and saved it. After that I added a new ProductPropertys, which fixed the issue.